# General strategy for limited steps Portal levels

Tags: achievements, portal

One of the challenges in Portal was to try to complete certain levels while taking a minimum number of steps.  Obviously this requires good use of portal placement, but I was never able to get anywhere close to the goals.  I don't want a walkthrough for the specific levels, but could someone give some general techniques that you use to complete these type of challenges?

Comment: I only have [16/17 achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/id/timko/stats/Portal/?tab=achievements).  At least I'm not totally [CDO](http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/tumblr_l57g7bx5hq1qaaafzo1_500.jpg).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Steps inside the elevator don't count.  If you run and jump out of the elevator, it only uses 1 step (if you don't move forward when you land).
2. Falling from one portal into the other is very useful and uses no steps.  With forward momentum and perfect portal shooting, you can chain a series of portals so that you jump into one on the floor, come out of the ceiling ahead, shoot and fall into one further ahead on the floor, shoot and fall out of one further ahead on the ceiling, etc.  ([YouTube example for #1 and #2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFBBdgs1Z18))
3. As you mentioned, portal placement.  A lot of the levels can be navigated around with only a couple steps if you're "thinking with portals".

Those are how I got all the gold achievements for steps in Portal, nothing more complicated.

Comment: "Steps inside the elevator don't count" doesn't appear to be true in the current version (which was free on Steam).

Comment: @Kyralesaa That sucks, but thanks for the update.

Answer (score 7):

This goes along with Matthew's general tips, but I think it's key, as you can't use the portals for moving yourself all the time, but sometimes to move boxes/etc.

- If you aren't moving too fast (from too high) when you land vertically (e.g. after going up and down through portals on the floor), it will not count as a step if you remove a portal from under you.  If you need to cut your altitude, throw a portal under a small overhang so you'll bang your head on that to spare your feet.

Comment: I never knew that, cool.  +1